Set write/read/connection timeout in Angular application
I've got task to introduce timeouts into a frontend application. Basically what I've done now is this interceptor
@Injectable()
export class RequestTimeoutInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor() {}

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<unknown>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<unknown>> {
    return next.handle(request).pipe(
      timeout(environment.requestTimeout),
      catchError(error => {
        if (error instanceof TimeoutError) {
          const timeoutError = new HttpErrorResponse({
            error: 'Request Timeout',
            status: 408,
            statusText: 'Request Timeout'
          });
          return throwError(() => timeoutError);
        } else {
          return throwError(() => error);
        }
      })
    );
  }
}

The problem is this one is 'request timeout' which cancel the request after certain time (and sometimes I can imagine situation where we have very long operation/slow internet connection and it can break the functionality). My question is if its possible in Angular to distinguish timeouts for:

read timeout - situation where the time between received chunks of data are too long (or getting the next chunk of data just hung)
write timeout - situation where sending process taking too long
connection timeout - situation where we cannot establish connection with host

I expected to somehow detect different situation and properly handle them to improve user experience.

You can not do that using the rxjs operator timeout, the operator and http errors are different things. What you are looking for is for the server to send you those errors, the server can be the api you consume or the webserver ( nginx? ), both of them must have the capability to detect and send you the correct timeout error.

its exactly what I did (see implementation) but for example when I cannot connect to the host, I need to wait ~15/20s, question is if I'm able to recognize I'm connecting to the host > 5s and cancel it then. The same is with read timeout: if operation is downloading chunks (slowly but still) is expected behavior but if between downloaded and upcoming chunk of data time is > x if I can recognize this issue.
